# What does wire loops on the wall for?

Tags: electrical, lighting, basement

I bought a house recently, and there are wires in the walls under stucco. But in basement these wires are go out as a loops not far from the ceil.

What are they for? Are they for lamps? If yes, then what it the right way to hang lapms on these "loops"?

[image]

Comment: That's likely "extra wire" so that if you find yourself short on wire you don't need to extend it, just unwrap the loop. A photo would help anyway.

Comment: Please add a photo.

Comment: Where is this house located?

Comment: What kind of wire? Bare iron wire or insulated electrical?

Comment: Added a photo. Wire is insulated electrical. House located in Russia, not far from Moscow (why this could make sense?).

Comment: Reopened now that the photo has been added. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure of typical Russian construction techniques but this appears to be standard non-metallic house wiring cable. You need to determine if there is current available continuously or if it is switched somewhere. A non-contact circuit tester would help. You would not hang lights from this. My best guess is you somehow mount the fixture base over the spot and cut into the cable to connect the fixture in parallel. If the cable is unswitched, the fixture needs to have it's own switching provision.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's a circuit for lighting, and the reason that it's a loop is the wire comes out from the stucco and then heads back in to go to the next light. It's quicker to do it this way then to cut the wire.

If I'm correct, there is a switch somewhere that energizes this circuit. If you can get a non-contact voltage detector, you can use that to verify which switch is hooked up to the circuit. Once you know that, it's simple to turn off that circuit and then put up fixtures. They would mount directly to the stucco.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a place for mounting an outlet - the wire would be cut, stripped and then both ends of the cut loop would be connected to the same outlet terminals so that the wire enters the outlet and then another wire leaves the outlet and goes to the next outlet. This way you don't need a junction box, because the outlet serves as a junction box. Not that it's a very reliable setup, but it's widely used because it allows for neater looking wiring. However the outlet is not there - perhaps the previous owner finally decided it was not needed so the loop was not cut and was kept closed.

Answer (score 0):

Further description of the so called wire maybe needed but these loops could very well be induction loops primarily used for hard of hearing users normally reserved for commercial environments i have on occasion seen them fitted in homes!